# How to install a vcpkg package without default options

Tags: vcpkg

Packages often have [options](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-introducing-installation-options-with-feature-packages/) that can be selected at install time. It's easy to add additional options to a package when it is installed: `vcpkg install package[option]`

I'd like to remove one of the default options selected for a package. How can I deselect options from a package? Specifically, I'd like to install [curl](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/ports/curl/CONTROL) with the `winssl` feature and without `openssl`.